# I'm trying to use Session in MVC 5 to pass the Id of a recently registered user

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session, asp.net-mvc-5, session-variables

I'm trying to use Session in MVC 5 to get the Id of a recently registered user.
I've got the code below but it's giving me an error saying "The name "Session" doesn't exist in the current context"

I added this statement using HttpContext.Current.Session; yet its saying "The type or namespace could not be found" what can i do to resolve thos error ?

```
public class RegisterBusiness
    {
        public UserManager<GlenwoodMed.Data.ApplicationUser> UserManager { get; set; }

        public RegisterBusiness()
        {
            UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(new IdentityDataContext()));
        }

        public bool FindUser(string userName, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            var user = UserManager.FindByName(userName);
            if (user != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        public async Task<bool> RegisterUser(RegisterModel objRegisterModel, IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
        {
            var newuser = new ApplicationUser()
            {
                Id = objRegisterModel.UserName,
                UserName = objRegisterModel.UserName,
                Email = objRegisterModel.Email,
                Password = objRegisterModel.Password,
                FullName = objRegisterModel.FullName,
                Surname = objRegisterModel.Surname,
                MaritalStatus = objRegisterModel.MaritalStatus,
                DOB = objRegisterModel.DOB,
                Address = objRegisterModel.Address,
                PostalCode = objRegisterModel.PostalCode,
                Telephone = objRegisterModel.Telephone,
                Employer = objRegisterModel.Employer,
                EmployerTelephone = objRegisterModel.EmployerTelephone,
                Occupation = objRegisterModel.Occupation,
                NationalId = objRegisterModel.NationalId,
                Status = objRegisterModel.Status,
                MedicalAidName = objRegisterModel.MedicalAidName,
                MedicalAidNo = objRegisterModel.MedicalAidNo
            };

            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(
               newuser, objRegisterModel.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {

                //Session["id"] = newuser.Id;

                await SignInAsync(newuser, false, authenticationManager);
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Adding to it I have a class to handle the register operations called RegisterBusiness it is located in a class library under my solution called BusinessLogic so Session uses System.Web.mvc namespace and the .dll for that doesnt exist in the class library i created What are the neccesary .dll's that i'm to add to the BusinessLogic class library because i tried adding only System.Web.Mvc but i think its dependent on others because its not responding as at yet. Can u help further ? Thanks.

Comment: can you use System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["blah"]

Comment: `HttpContext.Current.Session` isn't a namespace.

Comment: Is this code within the MVC project, or a different project in the solution?

Comment: U got it right different project in the solution @sq33G i've explained it further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to MSDN site, if you are using HttpContext.Current.Session, try this code:

```
HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
context.Session["id"] = newuser.Id;
var id = (string)(context.Session["id"]);
```

You could store other types than string, just cast session to this type.

From what you are have in code:

```
Session["id"] = newuser.Id;
```

This you can use in a Web Forms page class.

Edit:

HttpContext.Current.Session is in System.Web.Mvc. Probably this class that you present for us is outside from Web page. What I think, you cannot set Sessions outside WebPage clasess. This could be done in fe. Controller using easier way: Session["id"] = "id".

So my idea is to instead of returning True, return `newuser.Id` and assign it to session in Class from where this registration function will be called.

Edit2:
The solution above is when standard

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["Id"] = newuser.Id;
```

Doesn't work. Try this at first, but don't add any Using statements. You will need only System.Web.Mvc; to run this.

Comment: thanks for your contribution but my program isn't accepting this namespace (using HttpContext.Current.Session;) so i can't proceed with the solution you provided.

Comment: Probably you cant use `using HttpContext.Current.Session;` statement.
Please check my edit section

Comment: I added a detailed description to my problem ...please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to make your object smart about the concrete types it requires, I'd recommend using [IoC (Inversion of Control)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) (Implemented by any Dependency Injection framework like Unity or Autofac or etc):

```
public class RegisterBusiness
{
    // This most likely shouldn't be public or a property
    private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private HttpSessionStateBase _session;

    public RegisterBusiness(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
      HttpSessionStateBase session)
    {
      _userManager = userManager;
      _session = session;
    }

public async Task<bool> RegisterUser(RegisterModel objRegisterModel,  
  IAuthenticationManager authenticationManager)
{
  var newuser = new ApplicationUser()
  {
  //...

  if (result.Succeeded)
  {
    _session["id"] = newuser.Id;
```

then in the constructor for your RegisterBusiness:

```
public MyController : AsyncController
{
  public Task<ActionResult> MyAction(...)
  {
    // if you don't use DI
    var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(
      new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(
        new IdentityDataContext()));

    var registerBusiness = new RegisterBusiness(userManager, Session);

    var result = await registerBusiness.RegisterUser(...);
  }
}
```

I'd also recommend never using `HttpContext.Current` it's very old school and not easily unit-testable, it's why the newer MVC Frameworks implemented `HttpSessionStateBase` which is a wrapper for Session.

Answer (score 0):

You've tried to separate concerns by having a separate layer (project) do the work here. That's good - so let's take that a step further. Why should this layer know that you're working with a Web setup?

If you really want to keep the concerns separate, you can return `int?` from the method and put the result (if not null) in `Session` once you get out into the Web layer again.

If the separation really isn't necessary at this level, you can add a reference to `System.Web` to this project. But definitely think twice about the responsibilities of this class library before doing so.